# How to use I2C communication between two arduinos in simulink

Tags: arduino, simulink, i2c

I'm using simulink suppport package for arduino to program two arduino megas. I want to use one mega to send a number to another mega. I am trying to use I2C communication but have failed at it because simulink does not allow you to set an address for the mega sending data. So, I don't know what address to put in the mega receiving the data.

I tried another method which is to send data to a third arduino which reads it in arduino IDE where I can set an address for this slave arduino and then forward that data to the second arduino in Simulink. This method has not been working either because no matter what number I send to the arduino IDE it only reads 183. If I add a gain block in simulink then the number received in IDE is 187. it adds 4 for every gain block added, regardless of the magnitude of gain.

I expect one mega to successfully receive a number from the other mega. it does not have to be the exact number but the relation has to be consistent.
e.g. sent 1 but received 5 is okay 
as long as sending 2 receives 10.

Comment: According the [Arduino Simulink Support Package docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduino/common.html) it is not possible for the arduino to act as a slave device. The Arduino can only be a master device communicating with slaves. This is a limitation of the support package but you theoretically could expand this to add support for an Arduino to act as a slave device.